# Wrapping text around image, css only

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

[image]

What is the most efficient way to create this effect, knowing that:

- html structure can not be changed
- you can use only pure css
- image dimensions are variable
- width of the main container is variable
- amount of text is variable, there can be 100 characters or 5000

```html
<div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/320/150">
  </div>

  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut risus quam. Curabitur lectus nisi, congue a risus sit amet, dignissim posuere enim. Mauris eu arcu id augue sollicitudin dictum. Curabitur id lorem eu magna luctus molestie. Pellentesque ut est purus. Sed id scelerisque elit, nec condimentum augue. Nullam nibh nunc, dictum eget consectetur id, ullamcorper sit amet diam.<br><br>Quisque scelerisque massa ac nisi volutpat, eu posuere metus malesuada. Etiam ligula ante, faucibus sagittis dolor posuere, dignissim pulvinar velit. Nam bibendum neque sed nisl dignissim convallis. Fusce convallis sit amet neque commodo hendrerit. Nunc placerat aliquet libero, nec tincidunt ligula pretium nec. Nam a enim finibus, ultrices lectus ut, accumsan magna. Vestibulum quis vehicula libero. Aenean congue tellus vitae enim feugiat, quis varius eros porta. Proin mattis quam nec fringilla venenatis. Nulla mollis arcu non velit laoreet sodales. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam at cursus sapien.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I looked and didn't find the simple answer. Can you help me?

Comment: Set `.image` to `float: left;` and set `.image ~ *` to `float: right;`, maybe.

Comment: This way? http://jsfiddle.net/ogexL9sr/

Comment: and set each one to `width: 50%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the markup is very difficult to manage that. Though you can use like this:

```
.image{
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20em;/* you should set as your around paragraph height */
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="image" style="float:left;margin-bottom:30em;">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/320/150">
  </div>

  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut risus quam. Curabitur lectus nisi, congue a risus sit amet, dignissim posuere enim. Mauris eu arcu id augue sollicitudin dictum. Curabitur id lorem eu magna luctus molestie. Pellentesque ut est purus. Sed id scelerisque elit, nec condimentum augue. Nullam nibh nunc, dictum eget consectetur id, ullamcorper sit amet diam.<br><br>Quisque scelerisque massa ac nisi volutpat, eu posuere metus malesuada. Etiam ligula ante, faucibus sagittis dolor posuere, dignissim pulvinar velit. Nam bibendum neque sed nisl dignissim convallis. Fusce convallis sit amet neque commodo hendrerit. Nunc placerat aliquet libero, nec tincidunt ligula pretium nec. Nam a enim finibus, ultrices lectus ut, accumsan magna. Vestibulum quis vehicula libero. Aenean congue tellus vitae enim feugiat, quis varius eros porta. Proin mattis quam nec fringilla venenatis. Nulla mollis arcu non velit laoreet sodales. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam at cursus sapien.</p>
  
</div>
```

---

If you were about to change your markup then it would be easier to manage that by wrapping your `h1` and `p` in a `div` and setting `overflow:hidden;` which gets cleaner than setting margin-bottom in floated div.

Comment: I do not know how much text will be in text container. If there will be a small amount of characters, lets say 100, then this margin will leave giant hole under image.

Comment: I spent few hours tweaking this solution. Final effect looks like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/tmcx0u5s/1/

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved with your set criteria.  You will need to modify the markup. If you use Steve's answer the text will wrap under the image. Could do it with jQuery.

Comment: Oh wait.   He DOESN'T want the text to wrap even though he says so in the title.  I'm going to delete my answer.

Comment: So what do you call this type of effect ? My english is rather poor.

Comment: yeah, the image doesn't have text wrapping.  Maybe he does want the text to wrap, and just couldn't get the image to look correctly.  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Style:

```
<style>
    .image {
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }

    .OuterDiv
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

OuterDiv is the class name of the outer Div tag

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
            <div class="image"> 
           ....
</div>
```

Comment: @c97 sorry for late reply, seems you've got the right answer. but anyway, I cant fond what's the problem with the fiddle. you wanted to wrap the text, do you have any particular position for image as well?